# SQL Server Nvarchar and Java prepared statement

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I have a question regarding inserting strings to SQL Server 2008 R2. When I try to insert strings with some national letters, I receive "?" instead.

I know that adding `N` at the beginning of a string literal will fix this problem, but I'm using JDBC prepared statements, like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(col1, col2) VALUES (?,?);
```

My question is: How I can add this "N" letter? Should I do something like this?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable(col1, col2) VALUES (N?,N?);
```

To be honest I'm not convinced because this is not working at all.

Comment: The `N` prefix should not be necessary. Check the encoding of your Java source file to ensure that it is saved as UTF-8 so any string literals it contains are interpreted correctly.

Comment: Have you tried `sendStringParametersAsUnicode` method? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378403(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for hint. However, I've checked my source code files encoding and it is for sure UTF-8.

Comment: You don't need the `N` prefix. Using `PreparedStatement.setNString()` (instead of `setString()`) should work just fine

Comment: Try `setNString` as @a_horse_with_no_name suggests. I just tested a PreparedStatement inserting Greek characters into SQL Server 2008R2 using Microsoft's JDBC driver and `setString` worked fine for me, but perhaps your setup is a bit different.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please post this as answer so I will be able to mark it. BTW: Solution with sendStringParametersAsUnicode also works. Thanks :).

Comment: i have sql server 2014 and nothing works for me any idea ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on comments written by @a_horse_with_no_name and @gofr1 there are 2 solutions:

1. Change `sendStringParametersAsUnicode` - this cause that all string will be treated as "N" Strings (this is globally change)
2. Use `PreparedStatement.setNString()` instead of `setString()` - and this is "local" change.

Both are working - use which fits better to your needs :)

Comment: How HIbernate decides which one to use#PreparedStatement.setNString() or  setString() ?