# Oracle Query running slow with jdbc driver

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I am running ETL. There is a simple query given below

```
SELECT a FROM table WHERE b=? AND c=? AND d=?
```

where `b` and `c` are `varchar2` and `d` is `integer`. There is an index for `b`, `c` and `d`.

This query is running very quickly with MySQL. But was running very slow on SQL Server and Oracle.

For SQL Server, I pass the parameter `sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false` in JDBC connection. Now it is working fine.

See these --

- [Character data type conversion when using SQL Server JDBC drivers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2010/04/05/character-data-type-conversion-when-using-sql-server-jdbc-drivers/)
- [SQL Server Nvarchar and Java prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38654672/sql-server-nvarchar-and-java-prepared-statement)

**But for Oracle, I am still not able to figure out the problem and it is running slow. Any idea?**

I guess it is missing the index, as it was doing with SQL Server. With SQL Server, JDBC was converting string parameters to `nvarchar` that was preventing index usage.

Comment: What is the DDL (including indexes), how many records, define slow, what is the execution plan, etc.

Comment: Not knowing what ETL you're using, it's hard to tell you how to put [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html) and [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/constant-values.html#oracle_jdbc_OraclePreparedStatement_FORM_CHAR) information to use...  Also [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OraclePreparedStatement.html#setFormOfUse_int__short_).

Comment: Show us your Java code, especially the part where you pass the parameters to the `PreparedStatement`

Comment: Since you have not provided much debug information, such as that asked for by @MarkRotteveel, this is a guess. But it could that you have some (possible implicit) data type conversion going on, which would disable the use of an index.

Comment: In Oracle, when's the last time you gathered statistics on your table? `SELECT LAST_ANALYZED FROM USER_TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLE_NAME'`. To gather statistics use `BEGIN DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(ownname=>'YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME', tabname=>'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'); END;`, replacing YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME with the correct schema and YOUR_TABLE_NAME with the correct table name.

Comment: Below is the actual query plan i got through session manager.          SELECT STATEMENT   Cost = 1670        0
TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED IQ_FACT_PHASE      1  0
    INDEX SKIP SCAN ANEWINDX2      1  1

Comment: Table contains around ~ 400000 - 800000 rows

Comment: Please edit your question; don't use comments to add new information. Also make sure you include all information I asked for in my first comment.